# Removing text using pdfSweep - wildcard?

Tags: itext7

using `pdfSweep` to redact text - works fine when I know exactly what "string" I want to remove e.g. `ID: 12AAFF113` but I won't always know the number appearing after `ID:` so how can I remove `ID` and x number of characters afterwards -

does it allow wildcard support or similar?

```
Dim input As String = "G:/tmp/redact/input.pdf"
Dim output As String = "G:/tmp/redact/output.pdf"
Dim strategy As New CompositeCleanupStrategy()
strategy.Add(New RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("ID: 12AAFF113"))

Dim pdf As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(input), New PdfWriter(output))
Dim autoSweep As New PdfAutoSweep(strategy)
autoSweep.CleanUp(pdf)
pdf.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can use `PdfAutoSweep` and `RegexBasedCleanupStrategy`.

For example, in the following snippet it's shown how to remove all appearances of `(D|d)olor` regex string.

```
    CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
    strategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("(D|d)olor").setRedactionColor(ColorConstants.GREEN));

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input), new PdfWriter(output));

    // sweep
    PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);
    autoSweep.cleanUp(pdf);

    pdf.close();
```

The regex in your case should be "id:\s(\w){7}" or summat.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You do not need to wrap the RegexBasedCleanupStrategy in a composite. The composite is only provided to ensure you can chain various strategies (original author of those classes here).